# MariaDB Cluster to Cluster Replication Not Working when Non-Master Node Updated

Tags: cluster-computing, replication, mariadb, galera

I have two MariaDB Galera clusters (PROD (servers A, B, and C) and DR (servers 1, 2, and 3).  I have standard replication (Master-Slave) configured from the primary component node (server A) of the PROD cluster to the primary component node (server 1) of the DR cluster.  Each cluster can operate independent of the other as normal (i.e. if you make a change to one node, then all nodes in the cluster immediately replicate the change).

The purpose of this configuration is to allow me to delay application of relay logs on the slave for a predetermined period of time.  Unfortunately, MariaDB 10.1 does not support MySQL 5.6/7 delayed relay log application.  I am using a Percona script to facilitate control of the slave process to that I can vary the amount of time before relay logs are applied to the DR cluster.

When a change is made directly to the primary component node (Master - server A) of the PROD cluster, the changes replicate immediately to the primary component node (Slave - server 1) of the DR cluster, and then in turn to all nodes (servers 2 and 3) within the DR cluster.  However, if I make a change to a node (e.g. server C) in the PROD cluster that is NOT the primary component node (server A), those changes do not replicate to the DR primary component node (Slave - server 1).

I suspect that the process that drives the binary logging is not listening to changes in the PROD cluster manifested through the wsrep cluster replication processes running over port 4567 and are thus not written to the binary log files.

Is there a way to configure MariaDB so that a change on ANY node of the PROD cluster is replicated through the binary log of the cluster's primary component node (Master - server A)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [log-slave-updates](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/replication-and-binary-log-server-system-variables/) (along with log-bin) on the master node. By doing so, you are instructing the node to log the changes it received from other nodes into its binary log and thus will be able to replicate the changes to its slave(s).